# Why PostGIS st_transform length is different?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openlayers

I have two query

```
select sum(st_length(shape)) from sde.ways;

result is: 24268
```

And

```
select sum(st_length(st_transform(shape, 3857))) from sde.ways;

result is: 32047
```

Same Linestring geometries are calculated but the sum of total is different.

I noticed this while getting the transformed GeoJSON responses on my OpenLayers map. The total length of geoemtries on the map is different from database. My web OpenLayers map projection is EPSG:3857. So I am sending transformed data.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the result of: select distinct st_srid(shape) from sde.ways;

Comment: it is EPSG:2100

Comment: don't use 3857 for analysis - it stretches as you move away from the equator - see https://youtu.be/YES0UtBelNM

Comment: But map applciaiton projection is 3857.

Comment: Web Mercator is useless for length calculation, and there may be something seriously flawed in your use pattern if you have a table named `sde.ways`

Comment: The database feature geometry has EPSG:2100 projection. The transformed data settles on the map. But length calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use EPSG:3857 (web mercator) for length calculations. While it is in meters the projection distorts distances and will produce an incorrect result.

So:

```
select sum(st_length(st_transform(shape, 3857))) from sde.ways;
```

Is the distance in EPSG:3857.

```
select sum(st_length(shape)) from sde.ways;
```

Is the distance in EPSG:2100, which looks to be a local Greek projection, so should be much more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @HeikkiVesanto, this causes another [question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366856/how-to-manage-different-srid-data-in-same-database-table)