# How to manage different SRID data in same database table?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, epsg, srid

[image]

My data is in two different cities and three different EPSG code area. (Database is PostgreSQL/PostGIS.)

- So I think, I can not set SRID values by data. Making 3 different table is difficult. How can I do it?
- Data will  be collected with high accuracy GPS devices. It is also difficult to change coordinates in city borders.

If I use global EPSG:3857 for all data, the calculation of length will be different from actual collected data data. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your title highlights an option which is not available.  Your diagram shows a problem for which scores or even hundreds of possible projections exist. Web Mercator would waste high accuracy collection.

Comment: Please tell us the actual EPSG codes, and the required accuracy of length calculations.

Answer (score 4):

You can store it in EPSG:4326 WGS84 for example. Then cast to Geography from 4326 for distance calculations:

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html

Comment: Please suggest one or the other, but EPSG::3857 ('Web Mercator') is not a good suggestion. If you're suggesting 3857 but including EPSG:4326 to show what GeoCRS 3857 is using, that's already part of its definition. Using the name is probably clearer: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator.

Comment: Their data is already in 3857.

Comment: No, OP asked about using 3857 because his data falls in several CRS areas of use.

Comment: Fair point. Removed 3857 from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store as 4326 as the data spans multiple zones. Convert to a suitable projection to make calculations.